# Display icon on span class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to display icon after Firstname, and I put icon like but It doesnt show icon in @item.Firstname ?

```css
i.fa.fa.fa-heart {
        visibility:visible;
        height:25px;
        width:10%;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<td>@item.Firstname<span><i class="fa fa-heart" title="Arbitration"></i></span>
</td>
```

Button.OnCLick Function

```
$(".town").click(function () {
    $.getJSON("/NfDocuments/LoadMedicalProviders", { town: $(this).attr('data-town') },
        function (data) {
            $('#medProviders').empty();
            var p = 0;
            $.each(data, function () {
                $("#medProviders").append("<tr class='sortList' style='cursor:pointer' id='increment-" + p + "' data-id='" + this.Id + "'  data-lat='" + this.Lat + "' data-long='" + this.Lon + "'><td>" + this.Title + "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-heart'></span></td></td> <td id='distance-" + p + "'><br/></td><td id='duration-" + p + "'></td></tr>");
                p++;
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: You got a `fa` too many. Should be `i.fa.fa-heart`

Comment: Using the code you provided, the icon does show

Comment: It should still work as element with class .fa has class .fa. You should target as @MarcHjorth mentioned.

Comment: @MarcHjorth I change it, but still have a problem

Comment: @SimranjitSingh i put like 
i.fa.fa-hearth but still doesnt work

Comment: Make sure you included the Font Awesome library correctly

Comment: have you included `font-awesome` correctly ?

Comment: @Dennix I am going to ask very silly question, did you include font awesome css ?

Comment: <style>
        #mapedit {
            width: 100%;
            height: 400px;
        }
        .fa{
        visibility:visible;
        height:25px;
        width:10%;
        }
       
        
    </style>

Comment: Yes, It works know :) 
The font awesome css didnt include 
Thank you guys

Comment: If you have loaded `font-awesome.min.css` then your code will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have loaded font-awesome.min.css then your code will work. As below:

```css
 #mapedit { width: 100%; height: 400px; }
 
i.fa.fa.fa-heart {
  visibility: visible;
  height: 25px;
  width: 10%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<td>@item.Firstname<span><i class="fa fa-heart" title="Arbitration"></i></span>
</td>

<td tabindex="0" class="sorting_1">Michel Width, Doctor<span><i class="fa fa-heart" title="Arbitration"></i></span>
</td>
```

Comment: could you please check edited code above in my post
I need to put this alson in my function button.onClick

Answer (score 0):

`<span>@(item.Firstname)</span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>` Try this.